# Remove a Key from Dictionary by key name

Tags: c#, .net, linq, hashtable

I'm trying to remove a key from my dictionary if the key is a certain key.

parameterList is a `dictionary<string,string>`

```
parameterList.Remove(parameterList.Where(k => String.Compare(k.Key, "someKeyName") == 0));
```

Comment: Your question does not contain a question.

Comment: Your code would defeat the purpose of dictionary. Avoid using LINQ with dictionaries.

Comment: I would always take a look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac.aspx) first. IMHO this is the best place to start when looking for an answer to a .Net API/SDK question.

Answer (score 75):

This should be enough:

```
parameterList.Remove(key);
```

Answer (score 35):

Simply remove by key:

```
parameterList.Remove("someKeyName");
```

To check:

```
if (parameterList.Remove("someKeyName"))
{
    // key removed
}
else
{
    // dictionary doesn't contain the key
}
```

Comment: well I have to somehow check to see if that key exists then first I guess, otherwise I'll get a null ref exception if it doesn't.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, If dictionary doesn't contain this key, `Remove` returns false, otherwise - `true`.

Comment: probably something like if(parameterList["someKeyName] != null) parameterList.Remove("someKeyName");

Comment: Hmm, well when I look at intellisense, it's saying in the Exceptions area for this method, it can return a null ref...so where are you seeing this?

Comment: gotcha, yea it's only if it's trying to reference a null key name.. cool.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't even need an else :P

Comment: If you want to avoid the null check, just do if (parametersList.ContainsKey("keyname") {your code here if it exists}

Comment: @gorlaz to avoid null check you should use `if(parametersList.TryGetValue("keyname", out value){ ... }`. It is performing better on large dictionaries ( check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25662175/3741900 )