# Get Object stored in Dictionary using key

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm using a Dictionary object (C#) to store key (string) and value (Object) pairs.

I am able to store the Objects in the dictionary without a problem. However, accessing them is not working for me.

Here's the code I've come up with:

```
Object con;

if (dict.ContainsKey(theKey))
{
     con = dict.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == theKey).Key;
}
else
{
     throw new Exception("Connection instance unavailable : " + theKey);
}
```

For some reason, `con` always returns empty.

Comment: Why are you not using [`Dictionary.TryGetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ? In any case, value != key... Your comparison should be `x => x.Key == theKey`

Comment: I tried `x => x.Key == theKey`, which just returns the key again.

Comment: Also, why all the down votes? I couldn't find any questions related to Objects in a Dictionary.

Comment: I don't know why the downvotes either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
if (dict.ContainsKey(theKey))
{
     con = dict[theKey];
}
```

Here is a little script for LinqPad:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<String, Object>();

dictionary.Add("myKey", new Object());

var myKey = "myKey";
Object con;
if (dictionary.ContainsKey(myKey))
{
    con = dictionary[myKey];
    // con is populated
}
```

Additionally, you can see that in [DotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pwX5zc)

As per comments from Matthew Watson, using the following method is more efficient than `ContainsKey`:

```
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(myKey, out con))
{
    // con is populated again
}
```

This code conducts search once, where as `ContainsKey` and `[]` does search twice.

Comment: Thanks! The first part was all I needed and it works fine. Never used LINQPad.

Comment: @SuperJohn LINQPad is cool for little try-it-out. Or I added a link to DotnetFiddle - online service, similar to LINQPad.

Comment: @SuperJohn Make sure you use the `TryGetValue()` version above, not the `ContainsKey()` version.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Why do you say that? The `ContainsKey` version works perfectly fine.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Internal implementation of `TryGetValue()` uses the same private functions as `ContainsKey`: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs#474 Why do you recommend one over the other one?

Comment: @trailmax `TryGetValue()` calls the private `FindEntry()` (which returns the index of the item in an internal array) ONCE only, and uses that to return the value if it was found. Using `ContainsKey()` followed by the array operator calls `FindEntry()` TWICE. Therefore the latter approach does a search twice, which is clearly less efficient. (I think you must be overlooking the fact that the `[]` operator ALSO does a search.)

Comment: @SuperJohn See my reply to trailmax above. Using `TryGetValue()` only does one dictionary search rather than two.

Comment: @MatthewWatson indeed I overlook `[]` is also a costly search. Very good point, thank you for that!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use dictionary's indexer:

```
dict.Add("MyKey", new Object());
var result = dict["MyKey"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your comparison in `FirstOrDefault` is wrong, you are looking for a `KeyValuePair` by a given key by comparing it with the `Value` here:

```
FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == theKey) // pointless
```

But you don't need to loop the dictionary at all, you should use the indexer or `TryGetValue`. Since you have already checked that the key exists you can safely use:

```
con = dict[theKey];
```

However, if you're missing a method that gives you both, the key and the value as `KeyValuePair` by a given key, you could use this extension method:

```
public static KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>? TryGetKeyValue<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
{
    TValue value;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now you don't need to loop all entries with `FirstOrDefault` to get it:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict.Add("1", "A");
KeyValuePair<string, object>? pair = dict.TryGetKeyValue("1");
```

If the key was not found `pair.HasValue` returns `false`.